# Uploading a large video from iphone to web server

Tags: php, objective-c, ios, video, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a large video from iphone to a web server that has php script.

I'm using `NSInputStream` to get file video chunks and I'm creating a request(POST) on each traversal of the

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
```

method, with the read data passed as parameter.

Here is the code I'm using to get chunks of data

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode 
{
switch(eventCode) 
{
    case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
    {
        NSMutableData *dataSlice;

        uint8_t buf[1048576];
        unsigned int len = 0;
        len = [(NSInputStream *)stream read:buf maxLength:1048576];
        if(len) 
        {
            dataSlice = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:(const void *)buf length:len];


            NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:folderNameForUpload, kFolderName,
                                           @"abcd.MOV", kFileName,
                                           @"MOV", kFileType,
                                           nil];
            MKNetworkOperation *op = [self.networkEngine operationWithPath:@"upload.php" params:params httpMethod:@"POST"];

            [op addData:dataSlice forKey: @"file"
                             mimeType: @"image/mov"
                             fileName: @"abcd"];

            [op onCompletion:^(MKNetworkOperation *completedOperation) {

            } onError:^(NSError *error) {

            }];

            [[WebRequest sharedInstance].networkEngine enqueueOperation: op];


        }
        else 
        {
            NSLog(@"NO MORE BUFFER!");
        }
        break;
    }


    case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
    {
        [stream close];
        [stream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                          forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [stream release];
        stream = nil;
        break;
    }
}
}
```

It is sending the data to the server, and I'm able to  write the chunks into a file. But, the problem is that, if there are more than one chunk, the file will become corrupted and I'm not able to open the video file.

I checked the file size on both server and client, and both are exactly same.

Below is the php script, I'm using to merge video file chunks.

```
        $tmp_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

        $write_handle = fopen($fileURL, "ab+");
        $read_handle = fopen($tmp_file, "rb");

        $contents = fread($read_handle, filesize($tmp_file));
        fwrite($write_handle, $contents);

        fclose($write_handle);
        fclose($read_handle);
```

What Am I doing wrong here?, Please help!

I'm stuck over this problem!!

Thanks in Advance,

Suraj

Comment: Hi, Suran. I also want to upload large video in the form of chunks of data from iphone to a web server. How you did this? Do you have any tutorial or any working sample code?

Comment: Hi iOSDev, the code, that I've posted above is a working code to post large videos to server. Use an input stream, read video data as data slices and send them to server using NSURLConnection. At the server, write a php file to merge the chunks.

Comment: @Suran, Can you plz post your full code with loop to send data, I think this is just chunk logic, if you can post your all function with logic than it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem myself guys. Actually, I was sending different chunks of video at the same time. And the problem was arising because the later chunks of video reached server before the first chunk of video.

I solved the problem by sending second chunk of video only after the first chunk is reached web server and the response is got at the client side.

Comment: In the code posted in the question, check the switch case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable. in that part, I'm reading chunks of video data and sending them to server.

Comment: No, it will be sending data, when a particular number of bytes have been read. In this case 1048576bytes/1MB.

Comment: @Suran, Can you plz post your full code with loop to send data, I think this is just chunk logic, if you can post your all function with logic than it would be very helpful.