# upload large video using chunks via http post

Tags: ios, ipad, http, file-upload, chunking

I want to upload a large video from iPhone to a web server. I tried with below code. It's working for small files but when I try to upload large file it gets crashed.

**Code:**

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest
                                requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/submit.php"]];

NSData *webData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:movieUrl];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [webData length]];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];

---- added some HTTP headers here ----

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];
[postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:webData]];
[request setHTTPBody:postbody];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

After research I got an idea as , this will be possible if I send large file in chunk of data. [solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15529258/1635315) , [solution2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288969/uploading-a-large-video-from-iphone-to-web-server).

I also gone through [Stream Programming apple doc.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15529258/1635315)
But don't know where to define server NSURL. After writing data into output stream how to send to the server.

If someone can point me to any working code then i will be able to understatnd it better.

How to do that? Have any idea?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel.  Just use AFNetworking.  It has functions to upload and download using streams.  See here -> https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ#how-do-i-make-streaming-requests

Comment: I have looked into AFNetworking also got an idea, But in example of Streaming Request, If I stored data into NSData then the app will get a crash because the video data is too large to hold in a NSData object at one time.

Comment: ...then don't use NSData, that's what a streaming request means (streaming directly from a file).

Comment: Hi, borrrden. Thank you for answering. Here, streaming directly from a file means what?  Give me some working sample code. I am very much new to iOS.

Comment: The link tells you what property to use.  There are some samples also listed on the main page of that git hub.  I don't have time to write sample code (which is why I didn't answer) but if you look at the documentation for the various classes (including NSInputStream) you should be able to work it out.